# First line of Richtext is not shown.. toolstrip control

Tags: c#

This is the results output form  for my application. I am using a richtextbox where I load the results file.Results are calculated in the previous form and saved to a file. This file is loaded in the Richtextbox control here in the results form

```
private void frmResults_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Icon = Program.AppIcon;
            _mode = Mode.Load;
            richTabular.Left = 0;
            richTabular.Top = 0;
            richTabular.Size = this.ClientSize;
            this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
  FileInfo fil = new FileInfo(Program.caseFile + ".rpt");
            if (fil.Exists)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (fil.Length < 64000000)
                    {
                        richTabular.LoadFile(Program.caseFile + ".rpt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = Program.caseFile + ".rpt";
                        //  richTabular.LoadFile("RVEST.rpt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                    }
                }

    }
```

This is how the output appears on the screen. 
[image]
Now this output can be saved, printed.... All these commands are available for the user.I've used a toolstrip control for this. Looks like the Menustrip- ToolStripMenuItem  is covering the first line of output n the previous case. This is how the saved file looks like and is supposed to look like this. The first line is missing in the first (previous) screenshot.

[image]

Output differs (see snapshots).

"RVT Software Alpha 1.00.25" missing in the first screen shot. Could be that the Menustrip- ToolStripMenuItem  control  leaves an empty line?

Any suggestions

Comment: i'd suggest providing a little bit more context for your question

Comment: I believe this has to do with the order in which the controls are rendered.  Go to the Document Outline and move the controls (drap and drop in Document Outline view) around and see if that helps.